# Spring JPA Repository - Separate Insert and Update Method

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

How to create custom method from Spring JPA Repository that **separates insert and update functionality**? Let's say **create method for insert**, and **update method for update**.

Extra question:
**Why Spring JPA Repository doesn't separate those methods by design?**

My current implementation is **create validation at Service layer**.

**My Repository**

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {}
```

**My Service**

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    public void addUser(User user) {
        if (!userRepository.exists(user.getId())) {
            userRepository.save(user);
        }
    }

    public void updateUser(int id, User user) {
        if (userRepository.exists(user.getId())) {
            userRepository.save(user);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try to @Override save method when you create repository and so then create an update method. But i don't think that is a good solution.

Comment: Why do you want it, what do you want to achieve? @Mike: You can't override it, as the save method is written in the CrudRepository<T, ID> interface.

Comment: I tried it before writing and it was compiling so i thought you can do it. It was a try, but as i said it's not a good solution.

Comment: @Mike I totally understand ;) I also sometimes just give suggestions by heart which turn out to be not working :P all for just helping out other people here, I assume you try the same, which is great! :)

Comment: Hi. I need Repository-level or more low-level approach, so I can just call the method without create validation in every insert or update in Service layer.

Comment: Ok, I don't know the answer, but you might be able to find the answer within RestRepositories. Then you create @RepositoryRestController interfaces, which do implement the http POST and PUT methods the way you want it. I never tried using it that strict... Btw, rechecking your code, should it not be... public interface UserRepository implements --> extends CrudRepository<...>?

Comment: Updated thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its possible to provide your own extension to the standart spring data repositories:

Adding custom behavior to all repositories:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories

You could for example implement a lock function

```
void lock(T entity, LockModeType lockModeType);
```

But in your case, I'd suggest, to just leave the checks away, cause SpringDataRepository already checks if its new or not. If there is an ID, it exists anyway, cause you hopefully don't create your own IDs. It's all part of the spring data contract:

SimpleJpaRepository:

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: That validation only for validating new and current the data, so Spring JPA won't overrides it automatically. Because of that validation, I need to create many validations of all Services. Then I think there is a lot of insert and update validation boilerplates, so I need to simplify in a custom Repository.

Comment: I'd say you don't really need it, cause if you have a new entity, the ID will not be set. As such it gets persisted (isNew() check in save()). If you have an existing one, it will have an id and jpa will try to persist it.
The persist can have more characteristics like optimistic locking, that help find concurrent manipulation -> https://vladmihalcea.com/2015/01/12/a-beginners-guide-to-java-persistence-locking/

Comment: Yes, ID will not be set. But you can't prevent user to doesn't inject or add ID. Example of create method: HTTP POST /foo {id:1, attr:A}, if you just use save() the existing entity will be overridden (merge()) by new one. So I need to add validation that prevent user who use create method, so he can't update the data via save().

Comment: Or do you have other approach to secure that transaction?

Comment: You can ignore attributes in your HTTP facade. If you provide a form, that always generates new Items, just ignore what gets sent in the ID field. If you use REST, POST will insert, PUT will update (for example) and you anyway have to trust your clients or have to validate, if they are allowed to manipulate the submitted data.

Thats also the reason why I usually use DTOs in the HTTP facade and DOs in the persistence layer. You can now map the DTOs to your DOs in a controlled manner, for example your DTOs wont even have IDs, if usefull.

Comment: Nice. Thank you for DTO and DO words. Is there a good approach to cast DTO to DO vice versa?

Comment: Yes, there are many different mappers, like the old one: dozer who works with reflection, mapstruct, orika and whatever else is available. I like these baeldung tutorials thought you can give it a try: http://www.baeldung.com/orika-mapping